# If $A \succeq B$, then $\lambda(A)\geq \lambda(B)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B\in \mathcal{S}^n$ (set of symmetric matrices).  Let $A \succeq B$, which means $A-B$ is positive semidefinite (PSD).  I'd like to prove that $\lambda_j (A) \geq \lambda_j (B),\forall j\in {1,...,n}$, where $\lambda_j (A)$ means the jth largest eigenvalue of A. 
I was able to show this for the case j=1 and j=n (the largest and smallest eigenvalues), but got stuck trying to do it for other values of j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be easier proof, but the statement follows directly from the [Courant-Fischer minimax principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem).